# Prevent function calling before hyperlink clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

My problem is that the function runs before I clicked the hyperlink.
Here I create the link dynamically:

```
   $("#nearByCitiesDiv").append('<a data-role="button"  href="#/" onclick="' + showNearCityWeather(nearbyPosition) + '; return false;" data-theme="a">' + c.toponymName + '</a >');
```

and here is the function:

```
var showNearCityWeather = function (pos)
        {
        alert("asd");
        }
```

Comment: where can get nearbyPosition value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It assumes you want to append the value returned by the function to the onclick. Change the code to this.

```
onclick="showNearCityWeather('+nearbyPosition+')"
```

So your complete code must be.

```
$("body").append('<a data-role="button"  href="#/" onclick="showNearCityWeather('+nearbyPosition+'); return false;" data-theme="a">' + c.toponymName + '</a >');
```

Note the change where the function name just a string rather than being the actually function call.

Comment: Reddy is correct.  You are actually calling the function `showNearCityWeather`, when you meant to simply put the function there to be evaluated later when `onclick` is fired.  That's a simple mistake.  As soon as you throw the `()` following either a declared function or a variable whose value is a function, then it gets evaluated immediately.  You want this to be evaluated later, and putting "raw" javascript there will not be called immediately, but will be evaluated when the event fires.

Comment: But since its a variable I think the above is not required as the variable will evaluate to string anyways

Comment: Reddy - you were correct.  I have deleted my second comment since it was bad information.  Thank you.

Comment: @MuzafferAydin if this was the correct answer please mark it as answer so that it will be helpful for others with similar issue